# Switching between browser windows using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using a keyword driven framework and calling it from a `DS.java` file. My requirements as following:

1. Browser window01: perform tasks,
2. Open a new window02 browser by clicking on URL in window01,
3. On window02, perform certain tasks,
4. Close window02 and switch control to window01,
5. I'm getting error `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window. (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)`

`(Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

I have done with below mentioned code but it didn't work for me.

`(able to get the window handle here: CDwindow-b20d349b-3cb5-42ed-9f77-5229c88d4300)`

```
public static void store_ParentWindow(String TCID,String vTCD,String vKW) throws IOException, InterruptedException, AWTException, BiffException, ParseException{
    String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
    DS.envVar.put("parentWindow", parentWindow);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println(DS.envVar.get("parentWindow"));  
    }
```

```
public static void switch_ParentWindow(String TCID,String vTCD,String vKW) throws IOException, InterruptedException, AWTException, BiffException, ParseException{

    driver.close();
    String parentWindow = DS.envVar.get("parentWindow");
    System.out.println(DS.envVar.get("parentWindow"));
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the control is on parent window, when **driver.close();** is executed in **switch_ParentWindow** method. I would suggest that, you store the window handles, once you click on URL in window, that would result in opening of new window i.e. at step 2. You can do that using following code:

```
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> itr = handles.iterator();
String parentWindow = itr.next();
String newWindow = itr.next();
```

Whenever you need to close the new window, firstly ensure that the focus is on new window and then close it. You can do that using following code:

```
driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
driver.close();
```

You can then switch to the parent window and continue with the required actions. You can switch to the parent window using following code:

```
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())   // Switch to new window opened.
{
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}    
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);          // move to previously opened window.
```

Comment: your code didn't work for me as I need them in 2 different steps> By the way i have no issue in capturing the parent window handle or switching to the new window and closing it. Only problem is, i am unable to switch back to the Parent window after closing the new window

Comment: For Switch back to previous window use `driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);`

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck. thanks for your response